# Why do we structure dialogue/direct speech the way that we do?

Tags: quotation-marks, indirect-speech, dialogue

I hate how we format dialogue. I believe convention has gotten too heavy and we need to think a little more about logic. That being said, my question, to be more specific, is asking about labels for sentences with dialogue.

Let's use this sentence for an example: *Bob said, "I like steak."*

Now, I have seen grammars look at the structure in a few different ways. For one, you could look at it as if the speech is a direct object following the reporting clause. However, the problem with that is that this would be the only case where the subject and verb are separated from the object with a comma.

Another way that you could look at it is in comparison to a comment clause. However, if you do that, then the reporting clause, "Bob said", would technically not be obligatory, and at times, this may be true, as we see dialogue existing all by itself. However, there are times when the reporting clause is obligatory to its fullest regard; *"I like steak", Bob said, and then he picked up piece of meat.*

So, what is it? What is the relationship between the speech and the reporting clause? Or, is structures featuring dialogue simply so engulfed within their own gradient that we simply have to recognize it as something independent?

Comment: Have you not answered your own question? Sometimes, the "reporting clause" isn't needed, and you see passages of speech without them. Sometimes, they're needed (or, at least, helpful) so the reader can keep track of who is saying what, and sometimes they're needed when linking speech and other actions. How would you like to do it differently?

Comment: Per the text in my question, I explained that I knew the different ways it could be done; however, I want to know the reason behind the structure. Is it supposed to be examined as a comment clause, a normal structure with a subject and a direct object, or is it something entirely on its own?

Comment: You're talking about the written conventions of dialog reportage, not English per se. The big problem is that one has to identify participants like a play, but without using scripts, so the reporting verbs -- _say, declare, ask, reply,_ and the like  --get overused, to the extent that there are special constructions with odd syntax for reporting dialog, just to relieve the monotony, said he. So there is very little in the way of fixed grammatical rule here; we're verging on literary technique.

Comment: @JohnLawler I think I know which "special constructions" you are talking about, but can you clarify? Are you referring to the structure that we currently have for dialogue (e.g. comma placement and such)?

If so, this is where the problems I talk about lie. I am a fiction writer, but I work in the technical writing field, so everything I do is based on logic--and that's also how I am built to see things. So, I am just trying to find a way to sleep at night with the way things are structured. Do we simply say that dialogue is something entirely independent? Is it its own structure?

Comment: Migrate this question to Linguistics?

Comment: @Lordology How do we inquire about such a thing?

Comment: Well, Linguistics is no better place for it. Maybe Writing. This question isn't about English; this is about the English writing system, in particular the current American conventions regarding representing dialog in English spelling in English narrative prose (primarily fiction). Logic has little to do with it, but you may get some benefit from the [Logic study guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) and the [Verb Phrase study guide](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf), both made for a Grammar and Writing class.

Comment: There are many different ways of presenting speech in writing. The one given in the question is only the most common. There is certainly nothing preventing you from following other conventions. I've seen many books and pieces of writing that do so.

Comment: I’m sorry to point this out, and what you Posted in support of your Question doesn’t actually work.
First and foremost, dialogue and direct speech are not only not the same thing: they are largely unrelated.

If you’re worried about subject and verb separated from object with a comma, why not drop the comma? Drop it altogether, replace it with a colon or what?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Can you elaborate? I was under the notion that they were the same--or at least that direct speech followed under dialogue.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin I’m guessing we are elaborating then.

Comment: Yes, Alex, and could you look at your punctuation?

How would it be different if 'Bob said: "I like steak."

How if 'Bob said "I like steak."

Of course dialogue is always transposable to "direct speech" but don't you think that depends on why you're thinking about dialogue?

Don't you think most people's experience of reading dialogue is nothing of the kind but rather, simple reported speech - which is rarely dialogue?

Don't you think real dialogue is almost exclusively theatrical, and most people have little interest in and less experience of that?

Comment: I've seen an analysis treating the quote as the matrix sentence (/sentence substitute) and the dialogue tag (speaker + quotative verb) as an incidental, a pragmatic marker.